# Subset error when using a loop

Tags: r, loops, subset, glm, survey

I have been using this formula:

```
varlist <- c("A", "B")

for(i in c(1:2)) {
  print(varlist[i])
  print(summary(svyglm(as.formula(paste0(varlist[i], "~YEAR + REGION")), 
             design = subset(FEI.w, varlist[i] != "U"),
             family = quasibinomial)))

}
```

I have more variables than just A and B, but I want to do a glm in the survey package using A and B as my dependent variable.

The problem I am running into is that when I subset the data to exclude unknown values in A and B, R doesn't do it and includes the whole data frame.

Any pointers as to why this is happening and how to fix this would be very much appreciated!

Comment: Use of `subset` in functions and loops is discouraged (Ref: http://adv-r.had.co.nz/Subsetting.html). Use `dplyr`'s `filter` or something equivalent instead.

Comment: Use subset parameter of `glm`. Will give answer below

Comment: @discipulus `dplyr` does not easily work with `library(survey)`

Comment: @RichScriven i don't think that syntax works on `FEI.w`?  the class of that object is some sort of survey design

Comment: @AnthonyDamico is right. I tried the synthax suggested by Rich Scriven and it didn't work. Also, I don't think dplyr works since FEI.w isn't exactly a data frame, but rather a survey object that the survey package creates. Its non-traditional dataframe is part of why I've been having trouble finding easy solutions to simple data manipulation commands.

Comment: That's why we like to have reproducible examples.  I would have known it didn't work because I would have been able to try it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`subset()` uses non-standard evaluation, which means it takes the column names as unquoted variables, e.g.

```
subset(mtcars, mpg == 21)
#>               mpg cyl disp  hp drat    wt  qsec vs am gear carb
#> Mazda RX4      21   6  160 110  3.9 2.620 16.46  0  1    4    4
#> Mazda RX4 Wag  21   6  160 110  3.9 2.875 17.02  0  1    4    4
```

vs

```
subset(mtcars, "mpg" == 21)
#>  [1] mpg  cyl  disp hp   drat wt   qsec vs   am   gear carb
#> <0 rows> (or 0-length row.names)
```

Your `varlist[i] != "U"` compares the literal strings `"A"` and `"U"` and finds that they aren't equal.

You might be able to get around this with

```
eval(parse(text = varlist[i])) != "U"
```

i.e.

```
subset(mtcars, eval(parse(text="mpg")) == 21)
#>               mpg cyl disp  hp drat    wt  qsec vs am gear carb
#> Mazda RX4      21   6  160 110  3.9 2.620 16.46  0  1    4    4
#> Mazda RX4 Wag  21   6  160 110  3.9 2.875 17.02  0  1    4    4
```

but the old adage goes that if you're using `eval(parse(` then something has probably gone wrong.

Comment: Thank you so much! The eval(parse( fixed everything. I read a few of the other comments about using dplyr and using something other than loops. I try that in the future, but this works! You're a lifesaver.

Comment: If this answers your question, please consider accepting it.

Answer (score 1):

`svyglm` has a subset parameter so you don't need to call `subset` on the design object. You should do the subsetting like this:

```
library(survey)
data(api)

dstrat<-svydesign(id=~1,strata=~stype, weights=~pw, data=apistrat, fpc=~fpc)

rstrat<-as.svrepdesign(dstrat)

for (type in unique(apistrat$stype)) {
  print(summary(svyglm(api00~ell+meals+mobility, 
                       design = rstrat, 
                       subset = apistrat$stype==type)))
}
```